# VS2010 can never find my DLLs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I've tried all day to get VS2010 to run my program. I can only get the program to find the DLLs if I copy and paste them into the same folder as the output exe.

I have listed the folders containing the DLLs I need included under **Linker > General**. But running the program still gives me errors such as:

"The program can't start because tbb_debug.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

What can be going wrong? I am trying to include 2 packages which have VS2010 DLL binaries; TBB (Intel package) and Open-CV (Which comes with both DLLs and LIB files). For the lib files I am also setting them as linker inputs, though the TBB package does not come with vs2010 lib files.

I am entering full paths in the Linker settings, such as: "C:\opencv\build\common\tbb\ia32\vc10", where each folder contains DLL files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker is only looking for .lib files, which "point" the executable to the adresses of the functions in the dll. It has nothing to do where your executable will find the DLLs.

You need to have the DLL either in the directory of the exe - this is default search path, and is the simplest solution.

It gets slightly more complicated if you have different versions of DLLs installed which require side-by-side configuration. Then you need a manifest which tells your exe where to look for the dlls. Then you give the dll to the windows SxS cache.

Comment: this is not entirely correct. Default search path = first directory of exe, then the working directory, then the system directories, then the PATH. So you need to have the dlls in the search path. Which can be any of the aforementioned. Usually it's not a bad solution to put the needed dlls for your applications in eg 'c:\projects\bin' and add that to the PATH. This way you do not have multiple copies around (as with your approach) which is a must imo.